# PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable

Tags: installation, windows-installation, toshiba-hard-drive

My unit is toshiba Tecra R940 installed with windows 7. It became so slow and I think it could be with some virus. So I do reinstall of the OS. I load the installer on DVD, delete the partition with the OS and create a new partition but this time I got an error "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu"

I research on the internet and it was suggested to set the SATA setting to either AHCI or compatibility and UEFI mode to CSM. So I restarted the unit to set the settings on BIOS. After that I now get this error "PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable; PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent. Insert system disk drive, press any key when ready". What is this error all about.

I already read a lot about this problem but I cannot find a solution so I decided to create own question.

I also tried to remove the HDD and put it on enclosure. I was able to see and backup my files on the other partition. So the HDD is still working.
I also notice in BIOS that the HDD sometimes is not listed on the main tab. But when I do go to prompt and use diskpart during installation i can see the disk and its partition.

And also I set the boot order into: ODD, HDD, SSD, FDD, LAN

I also tried replacing another HDD on the unit and installation is successful. So i think there is not problem with the unit and BIOS.

By the way, this HDD is still less than 2 years from purchased and have this wipe technology printed on the disk. I don't know if it matter.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Do a factory settings (default) in the BIOS and try the reinstall, the stock settings should allow the original reinstall DVD to work. If not, it could be the chipset on the motherboard (not replaceable) since you have tried alternate drives. And the PXE errors are not  a problem, it is just a network boot error which is most likely normal, it just means it can't boot from the LAN which is often a last resort if no other media is available.

Comment: @acejavelin i think the motherboard is alright, since i was able to have a complete Windows installation with another HDD. Could be toshiba wipe technology a factor with this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said another HDD *didn't* work, my bad.

Comment: SATA port issues?

Answer (score 2):

Start by resetting your BIOS to factory settings.  I recommend disabling the PXE boot option if you are not using it (booting from a network).  Use UEFI and AHCI for Windows 7, but disable Secure Boot if it is an option.

Remove all unnecessary devices from the computer (especially other removable memory cards).

Though the error your wrote is not indicative of the issue, sometimes Windows will not install if the drive formatting does not match (MBR, GPT, NTFS/FAT) in all partitions.  If the above does not solve your issue, I recommend you back up your data on the other computer you mentioned.

When you have backed up your data, install the HDD back into the computer, windows does not like being installed via USB without further workarounds.  Run the installation DVD and delete all of the partitions to make a fresh disk, and Windows should have no problem installing.

Comment: thanks, will try your suggestion. I have already used another HDD and windows installation is successfull. I'm now using the HDD as the external drive. But I would like to use this HDD as its newer and have more space than the replacement

Comment: Following the above should be no problem then.  Just remember to keep CSM enabled, and if you have a SSD installed (as per your BIOS settings) remove it during the installation to HDD as well.